# R compare factor with value

Tags: r

I want to compare factor with values. I have a data frame

```
V1  V2
a   1,230,000
b   1,500,234
c   22,003,512
d   1,103,222
e   207,512
f   23,451

classify_V2 = function(V2)
{
income_level=   ifelse(as.character(V2) > 10000000, "B", ifelse(as.character(V2) > 1000000, "M", ifelse(as.character(V2) > 100000, "L","none")))
    return(income_level)

}
```

I wrote the above code to classify V2 but it does not return appropriate result.

Please help.

Comment: Looks like the second column is `character`.  Do you have comma at the end `1,500,234,`?  Convert the V2 to numeric and then apply ifelse. `df$V2 <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', df1$V2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the function

```
classify_V2 = function(V2){
 V2 <-  as.numeric(gsub(',', '', V2))

 income_level=   ifelse(V2 > 10000000, "B", ifelse(V2 > 1000000, "M", 
       ifelse(V2 > 100000, "L","none")))
return(income_level)
}
classify_V2(df1$V2)
#[1] "M"    "M"    "B"    "M"    "L"    "none"
```

Or may be you can also try with `cut`

```
 with(df1, as.character(cut(as.numeric(gsub(',', '', V2)), 
    breaks=c(-Inf,1e5,e6, 1e7, Inf), labels=c('none', 'L', 'M', 'B'))))
#[1] "M"    "M"    "B"    "M"    "L"    "none"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun!!! I was also thinking the same and tried as.numeric or as.integer but it return the absurd result.

Comment: @Ajay You have to remove the `,` before converting.